# How to show $e^x$ and $\ln x$ do not intersect?

Tags: calculus

I was trying to solve the following problem from a calculus book

> Show that the graph of $e^x$ and $\ln x$ do not intersect.

I tried to solve the problem by showing the function
\begin{align}\label{1}
f(x)=e^x-\ln x \tag{1}
\end{align}
does not have a zero (which is another problem). So,
\begin{align}\label{2}
f'(x)=e^x-\frac1x\tag{2}
\end{align}
In order to find the minimum of (\ref{1}), we should find the zero of (\ref{2}), yet another problem.

Comment: Have you drawn the graphs of the two functions? How are they related to each other?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Yes, they are the reflection of each other under $y=x$.

Comment: And if you also draw the graph of $y=x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already received good answers; so, just for your curiosity, may I welcome you in the world of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) !

$$f'(x)=e^x-\frac 1x = 0 \implies x=W(1)=\Omega \approx 0.567143$$ From here, everything becomes quite simple since, at this point $$f(x)=\Omega -\log(\Omega) >0$$

Sooner or later, you will learn that any equation which can write $A+B x+C\log(D+ex)=0$ has solution(s) in terms of Lambert function?

**Edit**

*This is totally off-topic but used for illustration.*

Let us try to find the minimum value of $k$ such that the curves $y=e^x$ and $y=k \log(x)$ intersect.

So, we look for the possible zeros of function
$$g(x)=e^x-k \log(x)$$
$$g'(x)=e^x-\frac k x=0 \implies x=W(k)$$ Taking into account that $k=W(k)\,e^{W(k)}$, at the minimum, we then have
$$g(W(k))=k\left(\frac{1}{W(k)}- \log (W(k))\right)$$ Let $z=W(k)$ to solve again $$g(z)=\frac 1 z -\log(z)=0\implies z=\frac 1 \Omega\implies k_*=\frac{1} \Omega e^{\frac 1 \Omega} \approx 10.2817$$ Since $g''(x) > 0 \,\,\forall k >0$, for any $k > k_*$, $g(x)=0$ will show two roots $0 < x_1 < W(k)$ and $x_2 > W(k)$.

Comment: Great! I know it is "off topic" but do you have a good book on the topic that you recommend.

Comment: @marya. This is (to me) one of the most beautiful ("simple") functions. I strongly suggest you deeply work the Wikipedia page (it is well done and includes examples plus a lot of stuff). On the other hand, on this site, just by curiosity, search for **Lambert function**; currently, there are 2132 entries !

Answer (score 10):

If you plot the two functions $y=e^x$ and $y=\ln x$ you'll notice that you can fit the line $y=x$ between both of these. So one approach would be to prove that $e^x>\ln x$ in *two* steps:

1. $e^x > x$ for all $x$.
2. $x > \ln x$ for all $x$.

These two assertions should be easier to attack using your approach of finding the minimum of the difference.

Answer (score 5):

From the series expansion of $e^x$ you can get that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $e^x \ge 1+x \gt x$. Thus the graph of $y = e^x$ lies above the graph of $y = x$. Since $\ln x$ is the inverse function of $e^x$, it's graph is the reflection of the graph of $e^x$ over the line $y = x$. Thus since $e^x$ never intersects $y = x$, it cannot intersect $\ln x$.

Answer (score 2):

Your way leads quickly to a result:

- on $(0,1)$ you have $e^x > \ln x$ anyways
- on $[1, \infty )$ you have $f(1) = e > 0$ and $f'(x) = e^x - \frac{1}{x} \geq e -1 > 0$, hence $f$ is positive on $[1, \infty )$.

Answer (score 1):

1) $x \in (0,1]$ :

$e^x >0$, $\ln x \le 0$, $\\ $no intersection.

2) $x \in (1,\infty):$

$\star)$  $e^x =1+x+x^2/2!+...>  x$, since

$\ln$ is strictly increasing: $\ln e^x > \ln x$ , or

$x > \ln x;$

Combining with $\star)$:

$e^x >x > \ln x $, not Intersecting.

Answer (score 1):

The graphs of $e^x$ and $\log x$ in the first quadrant are symmetric with respect to the line $y=x$ since $\exp$ and $\log$ are inverse functions. Since $e^x\geq x+1$ holds by convexity we have 
$$ e^x \geq x+1 > x > x-1 \geq \log(x) $$
for any $x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

With $\displaystyle x > 0$, note that
$\displaystyle\quad\mathrm{e}^{x} > 1 + x\quad$ and $\displaystyle\quad\ln\left(x\right) \leq x - 1 \implies
\bbox[10px,border:1px groove navy]{\large\mathrm{e}^{x} - \ln\left(x\right) > 2}$